# UITabBarController with 6 real tabs associated with UIViewControllers

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

So the case is that: I have five tabs. On each tab I have "detail button". When it's clicked from particular tab it's needed to be shown specific information. This detail tab is my six tab (but without tab button on the bottom) because it's called programically

I have UITabBarController with 6 tabs associated with UIViewControllers, but one of theme I want to call only programically (no item button). So how I can set this UIViewController to be without tab button in the tab bar ? I removed the title text and image but still is set on the bottom bar. Any ideas ?

Comment: Just push the view with a navigation controller. No need for tabbar item in your case as you describe it.

Comment: it's bad solution - I need to call the detail tab from each of the rest 5